# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Hi I am trying to run a python file that has :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

I started in windows, I got the same error :

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysql
```

Someone told me don't develop python in windows, it's lot of headache, so I started the same project in Ubuntu, but I got the same problem :

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant/FlaskMysql/FlaskApp$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in    load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysql
```

Please your help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you install Flask-MySQL?

Comment: Thanks lot, now when I installed Flask-MySQL, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a virtualenv config problem
you should get rid of old virtualenv and make a new one like this

```
virtualenv yournewvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4
```

This is the link I referenced:
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/2877/

Answer (score 50):

Here is the official Flask-MySQL documentation:
https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#
You'll find that the current import syntax is as follows:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Answer (score 34):

Be sure that you install [Flask-MySQL](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$ pip install flask-mysql
```

<sub>[commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031981/eugene-soldatov), [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins)</sub>

Comment: This should have the green tick!

Comment: Well, this one is the CORRECT answer actually

Answer (score 10):

It's **flaskext**, so...

Change

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
```

to

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, so I installed `flask-mysql` using:

```
$ pip install flask-mysql
```

and the module name is `flaskext.mysql`

Answer (score 3):

First `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL` worked then `pip install Flask-MySQL` also worked finally... it was driving me nuts! I had taken to many routes to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

```
pip install Flask-MySQL
```

On Mac:

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error.
First I installed flask-MySQL

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

Then added below-line in app.py file

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands on your terminal (one by one:

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

On your editor:

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

# initialize your connection
```