# getting error on using mysql on python like from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL

Tags: python, flask

i am new to python flask and i am creating web app using python flask with MySQL and when i importing MySQL in flask i am getting error like below

> from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'flask.ext'

here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
```

Comment: `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
` https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638406/1755108

Comment: done its work thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

instead of

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
```