# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskext'

Tags: python, flask

I am receiving that error when I am running this code: `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL`

Here is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskext'
```

1. My Python version is 3.9
2. I've MySQL DB installed.(While installing, my Python Connector is failed and according to here https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101128, this is a MySql bug that still haven't be debugged.)
3. I've also installed Flask-MySQL by
   `pip install Flask-MySQL` , MySQL connector by pip3 install `mysql-connector-python` and `Flask-Ext by pip install Flask-Ext` . All of them are successfully installed but I am still facing with same error.
4. I tried every possible solution from [ImportError: No module named flask.ext.mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241924/importerror-no-module-named-flask-ext-mysql)
   . How can I solve it? Thx in advance

Comment: did you use `pip` or `pip3` for installation?

Comment: I tried both of them. In each scenario I am receiving the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install flask-mysql package:

```
pip3 install flask-mysql
```

Comment: I did but I am still receiving the same error

Comment: Did you created a virtualenv and activate to install the package? in windows it will be like: 
python3 -m venv venv.  Then:
.\venv\Scripts\activate

After that you can install the packages, if you are using vscode remeber to pass the interpreter of the venv file

Comment: @TevfikSastım you're having trouble with setting up a virtual environment in VSCode here's a helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code#54107016